# C# Web Request with login credentials to html form

Tags: c#, php, forms, authentication, request

I searched for others examples but I didn't find nothing...
or if I found something did not work properly based on what I wanted to develop

The question is simple, I have this html script of a web page that send posts requests to a php file...

```
<form method="post" action="./check.php" id="ff">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="username">
        Username <br />
        <input id="user" type="text" autocomplete="no" autofill="no" placeholder="Username" name="username">
    </div>
    <div id="pass">
        Password <br />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" class="masked" name="password" required="required" autocomplete="no" autofill="no"/>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input id="button" type="button" name="send" value="Log In" onclick="check();">
  </div>
</form>
```

I want send to the page username and password credentials using a c# script and verify with a response if the access (credentials of an user) are correct, so negative or positive response..
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You can use Selenium web driver and a headless browser to do that....

Comment: I've done this with C# but sometimes I had to attach cookies and include them in the POST. The response page you get from server will determine whether login was successful or not.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: It's true that when you post a question it should include what have you tried so far. Apart from that, as a developer if someone want me to do the job in C# I would require the URL of the page and valid credentials to log in. Why? Because with these details I can capture a successful login with Fiddler (or inspection tool) including cookies, parameters and encoding. This exact request is what I need to reproduce with my WebRequest. If you want to use Selenium then you need to provide html for login and success page.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the real url it is hard to give a complete answer but yor code should be something like this

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "username","???" },
    { "password","???" },
});

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var resp = await httpClient.PostAsync("...../check.php", content);
bool isOK = resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```